# how to send post request from curl to google cloud storage using gcloud json api

Tags: curl, post, google-cloud-storage

am i missing anything in the curl how can i upload any file to google cloud server using post request in curl

```
C:\softwares\curl>curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_OAUTH2_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/kids-74096.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media -d'{dsdsdsdsdsds}
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this question solved and you moved on with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946043/post-request-to-google-cloud-storage-using-curl)? If that is the case, please proceed to close this question.