# POST request to google cloud storage using Curl

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In the following *Curl* command, content type and content length and access bearer are attached to my bucket URI to upload a file to google cloud storage.

```
C:\softwares\curl>curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -H "Content-Length:100" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_OAUTH2_TOKEN>" \ 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/kids-74096.appspot.com/o?uploadType=media&name=newcurl" \
    -d '{"text":"something"}'
```

But I am getting this error:

> curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Formatted, rephrased.

Comment: 1) Do not share OAuth2 Tokens publicly, it can compromise your security (although they expire after 1h). 2) You have [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945050/how-to-send-post-request-from-curl-to-google-cloud-storage-using-gcloud-json-api) that seems related to the same topic. Is it solved? In that case, can you close it?

Comment: 3) Can you clarify what are you trying to upload? If you really want to use the JSON API, you can have a look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload) with some examples. But maybe you are interested in the [`gsutil` CLI tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) too. What type of object are you trying to upload?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to include a Content-Type header, and ensure that your Content-Length matches the length of the data you're sending.  Here's an example:

```
curl -k -v -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <your_oauth2_token>" -H "Content-Length: 8" \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/your-bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=yourobjectname' \
-d 'yourdata'
```

As suggested in the comments, you might find it easier to use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or the Cloud Storage [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to accomplish this.