# how to upload data to google storage without saving locally

Tags: elixir, google-cloud-storage

This code works well for me:

```
GCloudex.CloudStorage.Client.put_object_content("my-bucket", "my_file_name", "heloo")
```

I am trying to use now the swagger library [google_api_storage](https://hexdocs.pm/google_api_storage/api-reference.html) and this is what I tried as well:

```
  @spec upload_file(bucket_id, file_path, name) :: {:ok, media_link} | {:error, error_message}
  def upload_file(bucket_id, file_path, name) do
    # Make the API request.
    res = GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.storage_objects_insert_simple(
                    Connection.get(), bucket_id, "multipart",
                    %{name: Path.basename(name)}, file_path)
    case res do
      {:ok, %GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Model.Object{mediaLink: media_link}} -> {:ok, media_link}
      {:error, %Tesla.Env{body: body}} -> {:error, body}
      _ -> {:error, "unkonw error"}
    end

  end
```

I want to upload without saving locally, what function would I use and how?

 
[storage_objects_insert](https://hexdocs.pm/google_api_storage/GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.html#storage_objects_insert/4) - I do not see where I can insert the content body in the request?

in general is the any referance in the api to uploading data to storage in [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/)?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Google Cloud Storage API, you could directly supply the file data in the body of a POST request. You can find the Cloud Storage object insert API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert):

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946043/post-request-to-google-cloud-storage-using-curl)  for curl request

```
curl -k -v -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <your_oauth2_token>" -H "Content-Length: 8" \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/your-bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=yourobjectname' \
-d 'yourdata'
```

using the library, use latest version `{:google_api_storage, "~> 0.13.0"}`:

```
conn = GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Connection.new("TOKEN")

{:ok, object} =
  GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.storage_objects_insert(
    conn,
    "BUCKET_NAME",
    body: "Hello, World! This is the content of the file.",
    name: "file.txt"
  )
```

see https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/issues/1197